# unit vector of induced representation in $SL_2$

Tags: representation-theory

Consider the Iwasawa decomposition $SL_2 = ANK$, and let $P = AN$. Consider the modular function

> **Serge Lang $SL_2 p. 46$:**$$\Delta(p) = \Delta(an) = \alpha(a),$$ let $$\rho(a) = \alpha(a)^{1/2}$$ and for $s \in \mathbb C$ define: $$\rho_s(x) = \rho_s(ank) = \rho_s(a)^{s+1}.$$ Then $$\rho_s(k) = 1 = \rho_s(n).$$ The function $$\mu_s\colon P \to \mathbb C^*$$ given by $$\mu_s(an) = \rho(a)^s$$ is a character.

I want to ask about a crucial algebraic step in the following proof. Its rest I understood very well.

> We contend that $\rho_s$ is a unit vector in the induced representation of $\pi_s$.
>   Pf.: $$\rho_s(nay) = \rho_s(nan_ya_y) = \rho(nan_ya^{-1}aa_y) = \rho_s(a)\rho_s(y)$$

How does one get the last step? I supposed it has something to do that $\alpha(a)$ is the modular function corresponding to conjugation by a. That is, the following equality holds true (and was already proved) $$\int_Nf(ana^{-1})dn = \alpha(a)^{-1}\int_Nf(n)dn.$$ But 1) in the present case we don't have an integral and 2) the most that I could get then would be: $$\rho(nan_ya^{-1}aa_y) = \rho_s(a)\rho_s(nn_yaa_y)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $\rho_s$ is by-definition left $N$-invariant, since $\rho_s(n'ank)=\rho_s(a\cdot a^{-1}n'a\cdot nk)=\rho_s(a)$, and since $A$ normalizes $N$.

Thus, similarly, $\rho_s(nay)=\rho_s(an_ya_y)=\rho_s(an_ya^{-1}\cdot aa_y)=\rho_s(aa_y)=\rho_s(a)\rho_s(a_y)$.