# Inverse of spherical transform

Tags: representation-theory

For further notation see [unit vector of induced representation in $SL_2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435357/unit-vector-of-induced-representation-in-sl-2/437449#437449)

Let $f\in C_c^\infty(G/\!/K)$ and set
$$f_x(y) \colon= \int_K f(xky) \, dk.$$
Let $$\phi(x,s) \colon= \int_K p(kx)^{s+1} \, dk.$$
Then define the spherical transform as $$Sf(s) = \int_G f(x)\phi(x,s) \, dx.$$

Now Lang proves on page 83 of his book $SL_2$ the following formula:

> $$Sf_x(s) = Sf(s)\phi(x,s)\phi(x,s)$$
>   pf: $$Sf_x(s) = \int_Gf_x(y)\phi(y,s) = \int_K\int_Gf(xky)\phi(y,s) \, dy \, dk$$
>   $$=\int_Gf(xy)\phi(y,s) \, dy \tag{$*$}$$
>   $$=\int_Gf(y)\phi(x^{-1}y,s) \, dy$$
>   $$=\int_Gf(y)\phi(x^{-1}ky,s) \, dy \tag{$**$}$$

My questions are how to get to step $(*)$ and $(**)$. Why can we simply eliminate $k$ in one and introduce it in the other?

Comment: Possible typo in your $(*)$ line - $f(xy)$?

Comment: Yes. Thank you.

Comment: I did some copy-editing, including \tag{$*$} and \tag{$**$}, and spacing in \,dy\,dk, etc.  I also changed $G//K$ to $G/\!/K$, coded as G/\!/K.  I don't know whether there's a standard way to do set that last expression that may be more efficient than what I did.

Comment: Should $\int_G f_x(y)\phi(y,s)$ be $\int_G f_x(y)\phi(y,s)\,dy$?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for illuminating me on correct typography :D

Answer (score 0):

Note that by the invariance of the Haar measure $\phi(kx,s) = \phi(x,s)$. This is used in $(*)$

Furthermore $f(ky) = f(y)$ by definition, this and $y \mapsto ky$ is used implicitly in $(**)$.